# Regexp to find content of HTML form

Tags: python, regex

I'm having troubles finding the content of HTML forms (or any other tag for that matter). I've tried

```
    forms = re.findall('<form.*/form>', htmltext)
```

but with no results. Where's the mistake?

Comment: You'd be far better of using a HTML parser; BeautifulSoup is excellent.

Comment: Thanks to both for the advice. I still don't understand why the regexp isn't working though.

Comment: Never ever ever ever parse html with regex http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks, those were real eye-opener! But what if the line I posted above (corrected of course) is the only parsing I need in a program? Is is still worth it to import external libraries or use many more lines of code of e.g. HTMLParser?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the form was on one line, that won't work, you need re.DOTALL as an option

```
forms = re.findall('<form.*/form>', htmltext, re.DOTALL)
```

You could use re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL in case you need to catch something like `<Form ...`